# Permissions issue with Flask app.config.from_envvar on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a Flask app to an AWS EC2 linux instance using Elastic Beanstalk. In my app.py I am loading environment-specific configuration using `app.config.from_envvar('FLASK_SETTINGS_FILE', silent=True)`.  I am setting the env. variable `FLASK_SETTINGS_FILE` in the EB web console under Software, the value being `'/home/ec2-user/myappconfig/flask_sit.cfg'`. There is a folder `myappconfig` containing `flask_sit.cfg` at the path `/home/ec2-user` and the file contains my config. When I deploy the app, I get the following in the error_log:

`Unable to load configuration file (Permission denied): '/home/ec2-user/myappconfig/flask_sit.cfg'`

The permissions on the `flask_sit.cfg` file and `myappconfig` folder are set to read for all users.

I am unable to figure out where exactly I should place the flask_sit.cfg file. I am unable to create a folder in the root folder (/). The [Flask docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#configuring-from-files) only use an example path (`/path/to/settings.cfg`). What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT**:
Thanks to @marcin, I *understood* the issue. So this is how I eventually decided to do things. Sharing it here, FWIW:

1. SSHed into the remote server, using my ec2-user key.
2. Navigated to the filesystem root folder (/). Using `sudo mkdir myappconfig`, created a folder.
3. Using `sudo chown -R ec2-user myappconfig`, made ec2-user the owner for the folder.
4. Then opened a command prompt on my local Windows machine and navigated to the folder where I had the local copy of the config file (`flask_sit.cfg`).
5. Used scp to transfer the file from my local folder to the remote folder. `scp -i ~/.ssh/<my key name> flask_sit.cfg ec2-user@<remoteServerIP>:/myappconfig`
6. Deploy the app. No more errors.
7. **Next steps**, once I figure out which user the application runs under, I would change the permissions to read-only for that user.

Answer (score 1):

Your app executes under `webapp` user. Subsequently, it will have **no access** to `/home/ec2-user` folder.

You can try storing the config files in different location, e.g. `/home/webapp` or in your current application folder.

Comment: Thanks, @marcin. I did not think of this. But I do have some follow up questions:
1. I had changed the permissions on  ```/home/ec2-user/myappconfig/flask_sit.cfg``` to read for all users. Would that still not help?

Comment: 2. I looked at the ```etc/passwd``` file to see a list of users. There is no user called ```webapp```. Is there a way to check wich user my app is running under? I see possible alternatives such as wsgi and apache in that list, but I'm not sure which one's being used.

Comment: 3. Once I figure out the user, I assume I won't have access to the ```/home/<user>``` folder, right? How can I place my config folder+file at that path?